# How to insert a Libreoffice writer Annotation with a date using Python

Tags: python, libreoffice, uno, libreoffice-writer

*Please note, this is a self answered question for reference.*
Most of the references to `com.sun.star.text.textfield.Annotation` refer to `Date` as being a :: com :: sun :: star :: util :: reference but no end of fiddling about with the contents will actually create an annotation with a date.
Setting Date.Year, Date.Month and Date.Day will appear successful but the annotation itself still appears without a date i.e.

```
anno = model.createInstance("com.sun.star.text.textfield.Annotation")
anno.Content = "this is my annotation/comment"
anno.Author = doc.DocumentProperties.Author
anno.Date.Year = 2020
anno.Date.Month = 5
anno.Date.Day = 18
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is not always complete, or is not obvious, depending upon where you look.
For LibreOffice 6.0 https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/Annotation_8idl_source.html
The Annotation.idl is described as:

```
 service  com::sun::star::text::TextField;
 [property]string Author;
 [optional, property]string Initials;
 [optional, property]string Name;
 [property]string Content;
 [property]com::sun::star::util::Date Date;
 [optional, property]com::sun::star::util::DateTime DateTimeValue;
```

The key here is the optional `DateTimeValue` which it would appear is the item that needs to be set to provide the Annotation with a Date and Time.
`DateTimeValue` structure is from `com.sun.star.util.DateTime`
To create an annotation (with a date and time) in a writer document using a python script, use the following as a template.

```
from uno import createUnoStruct
import time

def fs_Annotation(*args):
    #get the doc from the scripting context which is made available to all scripts
    desktop = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDesktop()
    model = desktop.getCurrentComponent()
    try:
        text = model.Text
    except:
        # The macro has been called externally but LibreOffice was not running at the time
        return None
    tRange = text.End
    cursor = desktop.getCurrentComponent().getCurrentController().getViewCursor()
    doc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    # you cannot insert simple text and text into a table with the same method
    # so we have to know if we are in a table or not.
    # oTable and oCurCell will be null if we are not in a table
    oTable = cursor.TextTable
    oCurCell = cursor.Cell

    anno = model.createInstance("com.sun.star.text.textfield.Annotation")

    anno.Content = "this is my annotation/comment"
    #Use documents author
    #anno.Author = doc.DocumentProperties.Author
    #Use hardcoded text
    anno.Author = "Joe Bloggs"

    t = time.localtime()
    dtv=createUnoStruct("com.sun.star.util.DateTime")
    dtv.Year = t.tm_year
    dtv.Month = t.tm_mon
    dtv.Day = t.tm_mday
    dtv.Hours = t.tm_hour
    dtv.Minutes= t.tm_min
    dtv.Seconds = t.tm_sec
    dtv.NanoSeconds = 0
    anno.DateTimeValue = dtv

    if oCurCell == None:    # Inserting into text
        text.insertTextContent(cursor, anno, True)
    else:                   # Inserting into a table
        oCurCell.insertTextContent(cursor, anno, False)
    return None
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Section 7.7.2 of Andrew's macro document gives the following, although I have not tested it.

```
Sub AddNoteAtCursor
    Dim vDoc, vViewCursor, oCurs, vTextField
    Dim s$
    'Lets lie and say that this was added ten days ago!'
    Dim aDate As New com.sun.star.util.Date
    With aDate
        .Day = Day(Now - 10)
        .Month = Month(Now - 10)
        .Year = Year(Now - 10)
    End With
    vDoc = ThisComponent
    vViewCursor = vDoc.getCurrentController().getViewCursor()
    oCurs=vDoc.getText().createTextCursorByRange(vViewCursor.getStart())
    s = "com.sun.star.text.TextField.Annotation"
    vTextField = vDoc.createInstance(s)
    With vTextField
        .Author = "AP"
        .Content = "It sure is fun to insert notes into my document"
        'Ommit the date and it defaults to today!'
        .Date = aDate
    End With
    vDoc.Text.insertTextContent(oCurs, vTextField, False)
End Sub
```

The API docs contain the same information as the IDL file but are somewhat easier to read.
https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/textfield/Annotation.html

Comment: Thanks for the input Jim. If you do run that macro, you'll find that the resultant annotation has no date or time. I went through all of the documents I could find before fixating on `DateTimeValue` and it's odd structure (Backwards). In the documentation both `Date` and `DateTimeValue` specify "contains the creation date" and nothing more. This Q&A is a reminder to me and others struggling with this oddity. Specifically, if you want your `Annotation` to have date and time, use `DateTimeValue` and populate it's value as above. In addition, I didn't find a python solution anywhere.